# Analytical solution for $x^2 + ax^b + c = 0$?

Tags: analysis

Does the following equation have an analytical solution for $x$?

$$x^2 + ax^b + c = 0$$

$a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers,
$a < 0$,
$2 < b < 3$,
$c > 0$.

The closest I could find was [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667866/analytical-solution-for-nonlinear-equation).
If there is no analytical solution, would an approximation with a Taylor-series be the tool of choice?
<sub>Oh, and: Does such an equation have a special name?</sub>

Comment: Generally there is no solution in terms of radicals and rational arithmetic.  If you are interested in real solutions, there are similarities with root-finding for polynomials.  One can identify locations where roots exist because the function changes sign, and then approximate the root as closely as desired by numerical methods.

Comment: I want to use this equation in a spreadsheet, so a non-iterative approximation would be more useful. I think a Taylor-series should work but maybe there are better alternatives?

Comment: If your parameters $a,b,c $ are all positive real numbers, then positive real roots do not exist.  If you know something about the ranges allowed for the parameters, it would improve your Question to add that information.

Comment: If $b = 5/2$ you may have a chance, maybe $b = 7/3.$ I see, speadsheet. No, you are out of luck.

Comment: @WillJagy $b = 7/3$ would be very close, but it would have been nice if $b$ could be specified by the user.

Comment: You can find a series solution here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411224

Comment: Aren't Taylor series iterative?

Comment: @N74 Thanks! At first sight it seems to be about polynomials but I'll look more closely because I don't understand it yet.

Answer (score 1):

By given conditions you have for $0\lt \epsilon\lt1$ $$x^2+ax^{2+\epsilon}+c=0$$ therefore $$x^2(1+ax^{\epsilon})=-c\lt 0$$ since $c$ is positive. It follows
$$1+ax^{\epsilon}\lt 0\Rightarrow 1\lt |a|x^{\epsilon}\iff x\gt \sqrt[\epsilon]{\frac{1}{|a|}}$$

This could be useful for help of numerical calculations.